# How to move background gradient left position

Tags: css

I am trying to move the left position of the gradient. But it is not working.

Even after adding `background-position` property, it does not works.

```css
header{
height:100px;
border:1px solid blue;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #e20e0e 50px, #0000 50px);
background-position-x: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: didn't understood your question :( can you provide some visuals about what you are expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off background-repeat.

```css
header{
height:100px;
border:1px solid blue;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #e20e0e 50px, #0000 50px);
background-position-x: 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` property.

Check out the similar question which is answered already.

[CSS Background Gradient with offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885690/css-background-gradient-with-offset)

```css
header{
height:100px;
border:1px solid blue;
background: linear-gradient(to top, #e20e0e 50px, #0000 50px);
background-position: 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```